# cx oracle python interface error : unable to acquire oracle environment handle

Tags: python, oracle, pyinstaller, cx-oracle

I have big problem with my program written in Python 2.7.11.

When program is executed from PyCharm IDE everything is OK. Then I use pyinstaller to maxe .exe for windows. Running the .exe file couses only one error:

cx_Oracle.InterfaceError: Unable to acquire Oracle environment handle.

This problem is different than others because everything is fine in python environment. Only making .exe causes error.

[my path variable on windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EeK94.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

In order for cx_Oracle to work, an Oracle client is required. The easiest way is to install the Oracle instant client which can be found here:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index.html

Make sure you follow the instructions on the page for your platform.

Comment: You mean to download, unzip and set PATH (on Windows)?
I already did. Without doing that nofing works. Have you any other ideas? Everything is ok when I run program from python environment. So PATH is ok I suppose. Problem is that after compile my .py program to .exe by Pyinstaller I get this error : Unable to acquire Oracle environment handle.

Comment: Usually PyInstaller is used for enabling the application to run on another computer -- which may not have the Oracle instant client installed on it. The only other thing I can think of is that PyInstaller is mangling things. You can add some code to the start of your application that shows what is in the environment and which cx_Oracle is being imported. Make sure that the instant client DLLs (oci.dll and friends) are *NOT* being included in the PyInstaller package. You can also try cx_Freeze and py2exe as well as they work differently.

Answer (score 0):

Set ORACLE_HOME, ORACLE_BASE and LD_LIBRARY_PATH to correct values. After that it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have PATH variable to instant client.

Try to make .exe file with Pyinstaller **without arguments**

```
Pyinstaller prog_name.py
```

Then **delete** OCI.dll **from dist folder** and try to run .exe